# jquery allow only one of a group of classes on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an element that gets a number of classes added to it + removed from it dynamically using jQuery.  I'd like to ensure that I have only one of a set of classes on the element at a given time.

For example, I could have the .blue_element class that defines a font color, background color, border color, etc., and I wouldn't want that on the element at the same time as a .red_element class or a .yellow_element class, but I wouldn't mind it being on at the same time as a .small_element class or .big_element class.

Current method:

```
$('#target_element').removeClass('yellow_element').removeClass('red_element').addClass('blue_element')
```

This works fine but seems like it creates a risk for error, e.g. if I add a .purple_element class but forget to modify my removal code.

I'm doing this on a larger scale than in my example and may be adding and removing classes quite frequently, so I'd expect to make some boneheaded mistakes if I do it this way.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You can use `removeClass` to remove multiple classes in one call, `removeClass('yellow_element red_element …')` – so you might just want to add _all_ your color classes in there. Even then one you are then adding again with the following `addClass`, that should do no harm. Or you could even use `removeClass()` without any parameter, then it will simply remove _all_ classes from the element – of course that only works if you have no other classes on the element that need to remain. (If you do, those could maybe be eliminated by changing your CSS selectors.)

Comment: Like CBroe writes, it seems like you really just want to call `removeClass` without arguments and remove all classes, or just set the `class` attribute directly

Comment: Thanks guys - I guess there's no great way to do it - I'll at least set/unset my classes in a separate function so it's in one place for all the places and times these classes are set

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jQuery use native mathod

```
document.getElementById("target_element").className = 'blue_element';
```

Above code will remove all classes and keep/add only 'blue_element';